# ELASTICBEAN worker default path needs to be changed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Can someone please guide me how to change the default value of HTTP path from localhost:80 to some ec2 IP address in elastic-bean worker. My data is coming from SQS queue to worker. Now I want to get that message to some http end point like 72.10.0.1/hello. By default it is sending sqs message to "localhost:80".

I changed in cron.yml as well and configured the end point in worker under elastic

Comment: That's how EB worker instances are supposed to work - the SQS daemon reads the message and POSTs it to the server running on the worker instance. If you really wanted to, you could have your worker application re-POST the message to another instance, but that defeats the purpose of offloading processing to the worker instance in the first place...

Comment: Thank you for reply...but i believe we can change the localhost to some static ip as well...

Comment: You're free to believe whatever you wish, but the documentation (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html) is pretty clear that the daemon will only POST to `localhost`.

Comment: Unfortunately no, EB worker instances are configured to always send the message to localhost altough you can change the HTTP Path that process the request to something like /hello

I don´t know the specific requirements but if you need to request a custom IP you can dot it by forwarding the request to that IP right within your code.